# How to count the frequency of words with CountVectorizer in spark ML?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The below code gives a count vector for each row in the DataFrame:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{CountVectorizer, CountVectorizerModel}

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, Array("a", "b", "c")),
  (1, Array("a", "b", "b", "c", "a"))
)).toDF("id", "words")

// fit a CountVectorizerModel from the corpus
val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .fit(df)


cvModel.transform(df).show(false)
```

The result is:

```
+---+---------------+-------------------------+
|id |words          |features                 |
+---+---------------+-------------------------+
|0  |[a, b, c]      |(3,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|1  |[a, b, b, c, a]|(3,[0,1,2],[2.0,2.0,1.0])|
+---+---------------+-------------------------+
```

How to get total counts of each words, like:

```
+---+------+------+
|id |words |counts|
+---+------+------+
|0  |a     |  3   |
|1  |b     |  3   |
|2  |c     |  2   |
+---+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `explode` and `groupBy` to get the `count` of each word

```
cvModel.transform(df).withColumn("words", explode($"words"))
  .groupBy($"words")
  .agg(count($"words").as("counts"))
  .withColumn("id", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("words")) -1)
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----+------+---+
|words|counts|id |
+-----+------+---+
|a    |3     |1  |
|b    |3     |2  |
|c    |2     |3  |
+-----+------+---+
```

Comment: But this answer doesn't actually use the CountVectorizer's model at all, does it? It just uses other Spark functions, like `explode` and `groupBy` on the raw `words` column.

Answer (score 3):

Shankar's answer only gives you the actual frequencies if the `CountVectorizer` model keeps every single word in the corpus (e.g. no `minDF` or `VocabSize` limitations). In these cases you can use [`Summarizer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-statistics.html#summarizer) to directly sum each `Vector`. Note: this requires Spark 2.3+ for `Summarizer`.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Summarizer.metrics

// You need to select normL1 and another item (like mean) because, for some reason, Spark
// won't allow one Vector to be selected at a time (at least in 2.4)
val totalCounts = cvModel.transform(df)
    .select(metrics("normL1", "mean").summary($"features").as("summary"))
    .select("summary.normL1", "summary.mean")
    .as[(Vector, Vector)]
    .first()
    ._1
```

You'll then have to zip `totalCounts` with `cvModel.vocabulary` to get the words themselves.